# Criação de uma nova view em um Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc

Em um projeto Rails, criei um Scaffold Responsability e consequentemente o Rails criou toda a estrutura básica deste Scaffold.

Criei um relacionamento has_and_belongs_to_many entre um model `responsability` e um model `Knowledge`, e ai será exibido vários check_box com os knowledges disponíveis para uma determinada Reponsability. Se eu colocar este código no `form`, funciona, mas ao criar uma view nested_knowledges.html.erb o conteúdo com os check_box's não está sendo exibido. Alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?

responsabilities_controller.rb

```
  def knowledges
    params[:responsability][:knowledge_ids] ||= []

    render :nested_knowledges
     @responsability = Responsability.all
     @knowledge = Knowledge.all
  end
```

model Reponsabilitiy.rb

```
class Responsability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :setor
  has_and_belongs_to_many :knowledges
  validates_presence_of :nome, :setor_id  
  validates_uniqueness_of :nome
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :knowledges
  attr_accessible :atribuicoes, :experiencia, :formacao, :id, :missao, :nome, :setor_id, :knowledge_ids
  default_scope order('nome ASC') 
end
```

model Knowledge.rb

```
class Knowledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :responsabilities
  validates_presence_of :nome
  validates_uniqueness_of :nome
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :responsabilities
  attr_accessible :id, :nome, :responsability_ids
  default_scope order('nome ASC') 
end
```

View nested_knowledges.html.erb

```
<h1> <%= link_to l(:lbl_responsability), responsabilities_path %> &#187; <%= link_to l(:lbl_knowledge), knowledges_path %> &#187; </h1>

<%= render :partial => 'tabs' -%>

    <div class="box">
  <% for knowledge in Knowledge.find(:all) %>
      <%= check_box_tag "responsability[knowledge_ids][]", knowledge.id,  @responsability.knowledges.include?(knowledge) %>
      <%= knowledge.nome %><br/>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 dias. Knowledge.find(:all) deveria estar no seu controller, e não na view. Algo do tipo @knowledge = Knowledge.all

Comment: Na view, em vez de usar for, use each. Ex.: <% @knowledges.each do |knowledge| %>

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma nova ação para seu controlador desta forma:

```
def acao
end
```

E então crie `app/views/seu_controlador/acao.html.erb` e cole seu código nele.

Então edite seu `routes.rb` fazendo o seguinte:

```
resources :seu_controlador do
  member do
    get 'acao'
  end
end
```

Isso deve criar a rota `/seu_controlador/acao` do tipo GET, apontando para tua página.

Lembre sempre de procurar suas dúvidas no *[Guia Oficial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)*.

---

## Atualização

Tente com as mudanças abaixo.

```
def knowledges
  params[:responsability][:knowledge_ids] ||= []

  # coloque isso antes do :render
  # note que em mudei o nome das variáveis para o plural, para seguir as convensões do Rails
  @responsabilities = Responsability.all
  @knowledges = Knowledge.all

  render :nested_knowledges
end
```

HTML:

```
<% @knowledges.each do |knowledge| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "responsability[knowledge_ids][]", knowledge.id,  @responsabilities.knowledges.include?(knowledge) %>
  <%= knowledge.nome %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Fiz todo o processo descrito acima @Andrey. Até a parte onde renderizo as Views funcionou. Quando coloco meu código na página criada, ele retorna um erro '< undefined method `knowledge' for nil:NilClass >'

Comment: @BrunoFonseca Tente uma vez usar `Knowledge.all.each do |k| (...) end` em vez de `for knowledge in (...)`.

Comment: Usei a busca da maneira como havia me dito. Funciona desde que eu tire a parte `@responsability.knowledges.include?(knowledge)`. Se eu deixar , ele apresenta o mesmo erro ... Tentei Criar um objeto de @reponsability e um @Knowledge na Action que criei no Controller mais nada de sucesso. Fiz algumas outras tentativas usando `knowledges` etc... e ele apresenta os mesmos erros. não creio que seja problemas com relacionamentos , alguma idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: @BrunoFonseca O erro que tu citou aparentemente indica que o objeto `@responsability` está como `nil`. Por favor edite sua pergunta incluindo o código da tua ação do controlador e também as classes de modelo, principalmente a parte de relacionamento (`has_and_belong_to_many`, etc).

Comment: A edição foi feita conforme solicitado @Andrey. Espero que haja alguma maneira prática de fazer este processo.

Comment: @BrunoFonseca Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass):
   <%= render :partial => 'tabs' -%>
   <div class="box">
     <% @knowledges.each do |knowledge| %>
     <%= check_box_tag "responsability[knowledge_ids][]", knowledge.id,  @responsabilities.knowledges.include?(knowle
     <%= knowledge.nome %>` Ele está retornando este resultado no console...

Comment: @BrunoFonseca Isso indica que a variável `@knowledges` está como `nil`, porém está difícil saber porque, já que no controller estamos atribuindo `@knowledges = Knowledge.all`.